# A drawing is deleted in FILLPOLYGON , C#

Tags: c#

I draw a triangle on an PictureBox using the command FILLPOLYGON but the drawing disappears every time another window comes over the image or the whole forum exits and returns to the screen. What is the reason?

```cs
//In the following code:
Graphics grf = PictureBox.CreateGraphics();
Point[] point = new Point[3];
//Here I fill in the values
// ...
grf.FillPolygon(color,points);
//The triangle is created but deleted as soon as the window I'm working on is covered or goes off the screen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ever call `CreateGraphics`. Handle the `Paint` event of the control and use the `Graphics` object it provides. The control is cleared and repainted every time that event is raised. If you don't execute your code every time the event is raised, your drawing disappears.